# why ESP32 restarts when BLE enabled?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

while working on a project I came across an issue that esp32 restarts whenever BLE enabled. I don't know why this happen. And also its not happening on all device, the issue raised randomly on tw0 devices which I'm making.

Comment: no answer here, but a related conversation https://esp32.com/viewtopic.php?t=17949

Comment: And what's the console output when this happens?

Comment: [E][BLEUUID.cpp:116] BLEUUID(): ERROR: UUID value not 2, 4, 16 or 36 bytes
[E][BLEUUID.cpp:116] BLEUUID(): ERROR: UUID value not 2, 4, 16 or 36 bytes
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled.
Core 1 register dump:
PC      : 0x4000c2af  PS      : 0x00060630  A0      : 0x801460bf  A1      : 0x3ffce380  
A2      : 0x3ffce3ae  A3      : 0x00000000  A4      : 0x00000012  A5      : 0x3ffce3ae  
A6      : 0x3fff13b0  A7      : 0xff000000  A8      : 0x00000000  A9      : 0x3ffce360  
A10     : 0x3fff17ec  A11     : this is what printing on console.

Comment: Well, that seems like a really good hint. How about opening BLEUUID.cpp on line 116 and checking what is expected there?